# Handlebars template not respecting view member when set from render helper

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, observable

I have a form that can filled out on its own or embedded into another form, as part of a larger object. When I `{{render}}` the form from the containing handlebars template, the child template does not respect the observable on the view.

Parent template:

```
{{render "EditIntro" introModule embedded=true}}
```

Where introModule is a property on the containers model which returns a the specific submodel for the intro, which is a part of the parent.

Child View:

```
App.EditIntroView = Ember.View.extend({
  embedded: false,
  isEmbedded: function() {
    return !!this.get('embedded');
  }.property('embedded'),

  templateName: 'intros/edit_intro',
  // etc.
```

Child Template (relevant part):

```
{{! If this form is embedded, user must use the save button for the parent }}
  {{#unless isEmbedded}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;Save
  </button>
  {{/unless}}
```

I can see the property in the Ember Inspector Chrome plugin, where it is shown to be boolean `true`. I can set a breakpoint on the `isEmbedded` function and see that it does not get called when the child template renders, but it does get called when I crack open the Ember Inspector or when I use the Inspector to change the value manually. Finally, if I set the default in the `EditIntroView` to `embedded: true`, then the button is hidden like I expect.

So how can I get the child view to respect a simple parameter that has been set from another template's `{{render}}` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template apparently doesn't have properties which are only defined on the view as part of its context. Since the `isEmbedded` property is only on the view and not the model or controller, it needs to be prefaced with `view.`. So the working code fix is as simple as:

```
{{#unless view.isEmbedded}}
```

And that's it.

Found the answer in [this Ember question about class views vs instance views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663684/using-ember-js-and-handlebars-what-is-the-difference-between-binding-a-template?rq=1).